# How to display more than one list in a single page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, powerapp, sitepages

I have maybe 3 lists which all have information regarding a single account and I want them all to display in a single page.

Is it possible?

If I'm using Power apps to customize the lists, will it be possible to include all the lists in a single page (haven't tried this approach yet. I'm new to SharePoint and Power apps)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, it is possible to display multiple SharePoint lists on single site page.

You can use **List** web part for adding lists on the SharePoint site page:

[image]

**References**:

1. [Use the List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) - detailed steps to add & use list web part on page.
2. [Connect web parts in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) - If you want to connect multiple lists on page to filter the web parts based on another web part.
3. [Using web parts on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/office/using-web-parts-on-sharepoint-pages-336e8e92-3e2d-4298-ae01-d404bbe751e0?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) - List of all web parts you can use on SharePoint pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Does this answers your question? If yes, please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. Thanks!